# Apply Download Permission to Customers in Bulk in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to apply download permissions to orders in bulk in WooCommerce. For example:

Let's say I have 100 orders. They all have permission to "Product A." However, I created a new product, and want them to have permission to that as well, we'll call this "Product B." Is there a script, function, etc. to apply permission to an array of order IDs to a new downloadable product?

I've looked into [`wc_downloadable_product_permissions`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_downloadable_product_permissions.html), which looks promising, but not enough arguments are supplied to let me accomplish this. Any help/direction would be appreciated!

Comment: An idea: Instead of applying download permissions based on product directly, it could be more convenient in your case, to create a kind of  special attributes (downloadable families) that can handle download permissions for products in which they are set. This way when you add a new product that you will link to one of this attributes, extending at the same time the download permissions… This is a just an idea, now to get this work is another thing…

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec thanks for your response! In this instance, I need it more of a migration tool. I'm currently in the process of converting my simple product with download, to a variable product with multiple downloads.

Answer (score 0):

I googled a lot but didn't find any solution, alternately you can create a new order (create gift order using code) for all users and as per woocommerce structure/rule all users can download that product from my account under download link. It is not a best solution but your work will not hang.

EDIT: (Use below method)
Loop through all orders and add the product to all orders (You can add product in any order even after order completed), you can add product using below code:

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_id);
$item = array(
        'order_item_name' => $product->get_title(),
    );
$item_id = wc_add_order_item( $order_id, $item );
```

Then you need to add some meta:

```
wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_qty', 1 );
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_tax_class', $product->get_tax_class() );
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_id', $product->id );
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_variation_id', $variation_id );
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal', 0);
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_subtotal_tax', '' );
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', 0);
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_tax', '' );
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_tax_data', 0 );
```

Finally call:

```
wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order_id );
```

If your order have already downloadable products then user below code at the place above function:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) 
{
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) 
    {
        $_product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
        if ( $_product && $_product->exists() && $_product->is_downloadable() ) 
        {
            $downloads = $_product->get_files();
            foreach ( array_keys( $downloads ) as $download_id ) 
            {
                wc_downloadable_file_permission( $download_id, $item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'], $order, $item['qty'] ); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
update_post_meta( $order_id, '_download_permissions_granted', 1 );
```

This all should be in the orders loop and that's it.